# Near Infra-Red Cameras for Eye-Tracking

Tags: camera

I am trying to investigate the use of NIR cameras in eye-tracking research e.g. the use of eye-tracking with infra-red glint (Purkinje Image). What I would like to know is what Make and Model of camera you have used.

I understand the choice of camera will be dictated by the nature of your research. This is not important for now. I am particularly interested in off-the-shelf cameras rather than custom built hardware.

I would like to know the make and model so that I can investigate how best to support different hardware for an app that I am creating. I am trying as much as possible to make the app open-hardware.

The app is focused on the research community, hence I would to get an idea of the cameras you have used in your eye-tracking research.

I will then investigate the camera specs online to determine things like what sort of programming interface the camera supports, it's features such as frame rate, hardware region of interest etc.

Answer (score 1):

For my DIY projects I have used ps3 eyetoy camera which can capture 120 fps. Only downside was difficulty in removing IR block filter with a filter blocking the visible range.
There used to be open drivers for this camera.
Hope it helps.